# Concerning health cloudera hadoop (network interface speed)

Tags: hadoop, networking, interface, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am new in that area and have some problems with my hadoop cluster.

I fixed many health issues but health of my hosts is still "concerning" (still yellow and not "green", unfortunately). Can this depend on the fact that my hosts are connected through an old switch with a speed of 100 Mbps? Network cards of almost all servers support 1000 Mbps.
In the recommendation for resolving this error, it's was advised checking the duplex options. It would have "concerning health" if the all of my hosts working on half-duplex mode, but i've check it and they all have full-duplex mode.

Screen of Network Interface speed issue:

[image: Screen of Network Interface speed issue]

About Cluster installation options that i choose (if need):
1) Use Packages;
2) CDH5;
3) CDH 5.13.0.

P.S. How much does "concerning health" of hosts affect their work? Can I run complex tasks on them? I've just used the test WordCount and calculating the Pi - and they were successful.

Comment: It's a warning, not a critical service

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to @cricket_007's comments.  If you consider the [Reference Architecture for Deploying
CDH 5.X ON RED HAT OSP 11](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/reference-architecture/PDF/cloudera_ref_arch_redhat_osp11.pdf) as a typical deployment you'll see that the ideal network configuration is 10 Gigabit Ethernet (10GbE).[image]

Most of Cloudera Manager's warnings are meant for production-level clusters.